# How to Ajaxify a hyperlink (JQuery & Ajax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I have to dynamically populate content into a DIV on clicking a hyperlink which should pass a value (code) to retrieve the content from server.

How can I achieve this using JQuery, Ajax and Hyperlink? I know how to retrieve content from server using JQuery & Ajax but I am struggling on how to Ajaxify an hyperlink and pass a value?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could start by giving this link an unique id so that you could reference it from client scripts:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "link text", 
    "action", 
    "controller", 
    null, 
    new { id = "myLink" }
) %>
```

and then you could unobtrusively AJAXify it in a separate file javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: handle the results here
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Of course if the result of this action is a partial view HTML that you would like to inject on some placeholder in the DOM you could use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $('#result').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

YAnd if you want to pass some additional values with the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    data: { someParam: 'some value', someOtherParam: 'some other value' },
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: handle the results here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I will be having multiple links created in a loop and each click would load some server side data (Partial HTML from .ascx file) inside corresponding DIV's based on some parameters passed on clicking the links. I don't know if a unique id for link would work in this scenario. Can I instaed AJAXify my links using a class attribute? How do I access the parameters associated with each link?

Comment: @Alex, yes, in this case a class selector is more appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a string value (such as product code) as parameter using `Html.ActionLink`? It accepts only int as id but I have a requirement to pass string as parameter.

Comment: @Alex, yes it is possible: at the place I am passing null you can add whatever parameters you like: `new { id = "foo", param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2" }`.